# New window formatting

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add a line of text then a textbox then a button on one line one then the same on line 2 and 3 in a new window, but I am not able to use the .grip for some reason.

So when I run the script I do not get the 3 textboxes but do get the three lines of text and three buttons.

Please bear with me as I am quite new to all of this :(

```
def open_window():
  window = Tk()
  window.geometry('400x150+1000+500')
  window.title('PSX CFD Config')
  ip = StringVar()
  Label(window, text="Enter IP Address", font=("Verdana", 13)).pack()#.grid(row=1, column=1)
  Label(window, text="Enter IP Address", font=("Verdana", 13)).pack()#.grid(row=2, column=1)
  Label(window, text="Enter IP Address", font=("Verdana", 13)).pack()#.grid(row=3, column=1)
  Entry(window, textvariable=ip)#.grid(row=2, column=3)
  Entry(window, textvariable=ip)#.grid(row=2, column=3)
  Entry(window, textvariable=ip)#.grid(row=2, column=3)
  Button(window, text="Set", font=("Verdana", 13), command=file_explorer).pack()#.grid(row=1, column=2)
  Button(window, text="Set", font=("Verdana", 13), command=file_explorer).pack()#.grid(row=1, column=2)
  Button(window, text="Set", font=("Verdana", 13), command=file_explorer).pack()#.grid(row=1, column=2)
  window.mainloop()
```

There are no errors in the debug terminal

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're just messing the rows and columns :

the following displays 3 rows as you want :

```
window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x150+1000+500')
window.title('PSX CFD Config')
ip = StringVar()
Label(window, text="Enter IP Address", font=("Verdana", 13)).grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(window, text="Enter IP Address", font=("Verdana", 13)).grid(row=2, column=1)
Label(window, text="Enter IP Address", font=("Verdana", 13)).grid(row=3, column=1)
Entry(window, textvariable=ip).grid(row=1, column=2)
Entry(window, textvariable=ip).grid(row=2, column=2)
Entry(window, textvariable=ip).grid(row=3, column=2)
Button(window, text="Set", font=("Verdana", 13), command=file_explorer).grid(row=1, column=3)
Button(window, text="Set", font=("Verdana", 13), command=file_explorer).grid(row=2, column=3)
Button(window, text="Set", font=("Verdana", 13), command=file_explorer).grid(row=3, column=3)
window.mainloop()
```

---

Note : you may need to create 3 different `ip` unless you want the same text everywhere ?

Comment: Briliant thanks for your help! removing the .pack() worked :)